# In Redux, how do I update only part of a state object?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm still getting my head around Redux and wondering if my solution to partially updating a state object is the best way to go.

Here's an example, in my actions I have two functions - getA and getB, they share the same state and each update only part of the state. I then pass the existing state to my reducer.

```js
// Action
export function getA() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const existing = getState().myReducer.myObj;
    dispatch({type: PENDING, existing})
    // ... Fetch data "A" from API
    // On success...
     dataA => dispatch({type: CASE_A, existing, dataA})
  }
};
export function getB() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const existing = getState().myReducer.myObj;

    // ... Fetch data "B" from API
    // On success...
    dataB => dispatch({type: CASE_B, existing, dataB})
  }
};

// Reducer
initialState = {
  ...
  myObj: {
    keyA: null,
    keyB: null
  }
};

export default function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PENDING:
      return {
        ...state,
        myObj: {
          ...action.existing
        }
      }
    case CASE_A:
      return {
        ...state,
        myObj: {
          ...action.existing
          keyA: action.dataA
        }
      }
    case CASE_B: 
      return {
        ...state,
        myObj: {
          ...action.existing
          keyB: action.dataB
        }
      }
    // ...
  }
};
```

Everything works correctly, the existing myObj is passed into the pending state, then either A or B is updated depending on which action is called.

My question is carrying the existing state through the actions the best approach?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not you have already `existing state` in `state.myObj` and In `PENDING` action why you are doing this

```js
 myObj: {
     ...action.existing
 }
```

You can just do this `myObj = action.existing` if you want to replace full object.

```js
export default function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PENDING:
            return {
                ...state,
                myObj: {
                    ...state.myObj
                }
            }
        case CASE_A:
            return {
                ...state,
                myObj: {
                     ...state.myObj,
                    keyA: action.dataA
                }
            }
        case CASE_B:
            return {
                ...state,
                myObj: {
                    ...state.myObj,
                    keyB: action.dataB
                }
            }

    }
};
```

Comment: I see, so will passing in ...state.myObj keep the updated state? I was under the impression that the initialState object gets passed in each time.

Comment: Yes as you can see that you are returning modified state (`return`) that is mean you will get next time updated state.

Comment: Can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477055/how-can-i-dispatch-function-in-redux